# show div after submitting the form in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When the user clicks the submit button on a form I want to return a success / failure message on the form show me the demo

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are running into? Got Code?

Comment: At least post what you've tried so far. So people can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Message = "some message"
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Message))
{
    <div>@Model.Message</div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```